# SQL Server Management Studio cannot 'see' other network SQL servers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I have a test environment for SQL Server 2012 set up on Windows Server 2008 r2 as described in the 70-462 Guide. All the VMs reside in a Hyper V private network and can ping each other. The DC and SQL servers can all ping the other machines (the SQL Core installation gave me a headache for 2 days because nothing could reach it while it could ping the others. I turned off the firewall on the core installation and everything worked fine).

The trouble I am having is when using the SSMS I can of course connect to the locally installed database engine, but when I try to connect to the other servers on the network I see nothing.

- Connect from Object Explorer
- Browse for more from Server name pulldown in Connect to Server
- I select Network and the system searches but only finds the local SQL A.
- Nothing else is listed.

I have performed the following reviews:

- I have confirmed the SQL Browser is on
- All the firewalls are off
- IPs are confirmed on all machines
- Listening port 1433 is confirmed on all servers
- As stated earlier I can ping all the machines by IP and computer name
- In Powershell I believe I can connect to the remote servers. `SQLCMD SQL-B` (and SQL CORE) brings up a Numbered section with no error stating it could not connect.

I have done numerous searches within the MS knowledge base and the rest of the community but haven't seen a similar question posted. This feels like a configuration problem but I cannot be sure of that.

Suggestions or additional items that I need to check will be greatly appreciated. Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note that this forum is intended more for questions specifically pertaining programming. Your issue may be a better fit for http://dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: After you establish PING, the next step is use `TELNET` to establish whether you can connect on the expected port. Use this: `TELNET <IP Address> <port>`. Can you expand on: "when I try to connect to the other servers on the network I see nothing". Do you mean you are trying to browse to the servers from the SSMS tool and you can't see them? What if you explicitly type in the server name - what error/response do you get?

Comment: first, sorry for posting in the wrong section

Comment: Nick, TELNET did not connect BUT, when i logged in and typed the remote server name in the connection window I was able to connect.  When I browsed I expected to see them listed but it looks like I could type the server name. I added the other full SQL server and the Core installation.  So that works but now I am concerned about the Telnet connection.  Should that be a concern or am I okay since I can connect the databases?  Please repost your answer below so I can mark this as answered.  Thanks for the help but let me know about Telnet.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete your compreenhsive troubleshoot list, bear in mind that network access to SQL Browser relies on TCP/UDP port 1434 on server machines. For further information, see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165724%28v=sql.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: This did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure each of them (the SQL servers) are configured to use TCP and Named Pipes

Comment: TCP and Named Pipes were enabled.